# IllegalStateException when a getString() is called inside a Fragment Class when Unit Testing with Robolectric

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, robolectric

I am getting IllegalStateException when a getString() is called inside a Fragment Class

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment SomeFragment{1df37025} (29efd1d0-77c1-4293-a0f6-b808c7559cf4)} not attached to a context.
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:805)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:869)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:891)
```

**SomeFragment** Code

```
public void someMethod() {
    getString(R.string.some_res)
}
```

Test Code

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    val activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(SomeActivity::class.java).create().get()
    fragment = SomeFragment()
    fragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager
    val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, null)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}

@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun someTest() {
    fragment.someMethod()
}
```

Comment: can you try with `commitNowAllowingStateLoss()`?

Comment: `commitNowAllowingStateLoss()` results in a different error.
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment did not return a View from onCreateView() or this was called before onCreateView().`

Comment: @cutiko `commitNowAllowingStateLoss()` solves the problem :) You can put it as an answer for better discovery.

Comment: Added with some reference to the documentation and explanations for meeting SO standards, glad it worked @MadhurGupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be `fragmentTransaction.commit()` because `commit` is asynchronous so when `someTest()` starts, the commit might have ended or not. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction?hl=en#commit()) says:

> The commit does not happen immediately

Replacing `commit` for `commitNow` or `commitNowAllowingStateLoss` should fix the problem. From the same documentation quoted above, the `commit` method:

> Commits this transaction synchronously